# Parsing value of a field from content to a webform field

Tags: webforms

I have a content type named apartments. When i view a content of content type apartments i will give a button for requesting a quote. When clicked on that button it takes to a webform and by default a field value should be filled by that contents title. Please let me know the process of parsing a fields value to a webform field.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [webform node value](https://drupal.org/project/webform_node_value) module

> Fill a Webform field with the value of a node field.

Comment: I tried that module but its not working. Please let me know if there's any other solution.